# xcode tryinng to setup back button using an image

Tags: ios, objective-c

i would like to set up an image for my back button but i have my code set up that the app delegate is my master view controller.

This is the app delegate controller code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"backButton" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [backButtonItem];

}

-(void)customAppearance
{
    UIImage* backButton =[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: Yeah... and what's your question?

Comment: how would i set up a default back button and arrow to an image i have?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to do it globally using the **UIAppearance**.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:yourImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I had forgotten about UIAppearance. UIAppearance can be used to change the backGroundColor and backGroundImage as well. e.g. [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; or [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ScoringToolbarBkg"] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think I‘ve ever seen any code that creates views in the app delegate. I just looked at a bunch of code samples from Apple and others and all of them create views that are called by the app delegate. So the first thing I would do is create a new project using the Xcode templates to decide what kind of project you want. For example, in one of my apps I use a standard navigation controller to go to the entry view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        EntryViewController *evc = [[EntryViewController alloc]    initInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:evc];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Then in your first view (in my case it’s EntryViewController) you want to put the code for the back button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    // More stuff
}
```